# How to get access to an event raised by a custom button in MediaTransportControls?

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling

I have a UWP Desktop application that has a MediaPlayerElement with a custom MediaTransportControls. I created two new buttons in the MediaTransportControls to increase and decrease the MediaPlayerElement's PlaybackRate. I've already created procedures that raise the events when buttons are clicked, but I don't know how to access these events on the application's main page, which contains the MediaPlayerElement. How do I do that? Any help is most welcome.

XAML

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayerElement" 
                                AutoPlay="False" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="0,0,0,100"
                                AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" >
                        <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                            <local:CustomMediaTransportControls x:Name="customMTC"
                                             IsSkipBackwardEnabled="False"
                                             IsSkipBackwardButtonVisible="False"
                                             IsSkipForwardEnabled="False"
                                             IsSkipForwardButtonVisible="False"
                                             IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True"
                                             IsFastForwardEnabled="True"
                                             IsFastRewindButtonVisible="True"
                                             IsFastRewindEnabled="True" 
                                            IsFullWindowButtonVisible="False"
                                            IsNextTrackButtonVisible="False"
                                            IsPreviousTrackButtonVisible="False"
                                            IsZoomButtonVisible="False"/>
                        </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
                    </MediaPlayerElement>

<!--Custom Buttons-->
                                        <AppBarButton x:Name='CustomPlaybackRateDownButton'
                      Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                      MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='18' Visibility="Visible">
                                            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE70D;"/>
                                            </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                        </AppBarButton>

                                        <AppBarButton x:Name='CustomPlaybackRateUpButton'
                      Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                      MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='19' Visibility="Visible">
                                            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE70E;"/>
                                            </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                        </AppBarButton>
```

Code Behind

```
public sealed class CustomMediaTransportControls : MediaTransportControls
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> PlaybackRateDownClicked;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> PlaybackRateUpClicked;

    public CustomMediaTransportControls()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomMediaTransportControls);
    }


    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        // Find the custom button and create an event handler for its Click event.
        var downButton = GetTemplateChild("CustomPlaybackRateDownButton") as Button;
        downButton.Click += CustomPlaybackRateDownButton_Click;

        var upButton = GetTemplateChild("CustomPlaybackRateUpButton") as Button;
        upButton.Click += CustomPlaybackRateUpButton_Click;

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }


    private void CustomPlaybackRateDownButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var OnPlaybackRateDownClick = PlaybackRateDownClicked;

        if (OnPlaybackRateDownClick != null)
        {
            OnPlaybackRateDownClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void CustomPlaybackRateUpButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var OnPlaybackRateUpClick = PlaybackRateUpClicked;

        if (OnPlaybackRateUpClick != null)
        {
            OnPlaybackRateUpClick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You have redirected the button click events to `PlaybackRateDownClicked` and `PlaybackRateUpClicked`, so you just need to listen `CustomMediaTransportControls` 's PlaybackRate click event in your main page.

Comment: `var smtc = new  CustomMediaTransportControls();
smtc.PlaybackRateDownClicked += Smtc_PlaybackRateDownClicked;
private void Smtc_PlaybackRateDownClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   
}`

Comment: Does above code work for your scenario?

Comment: Yea! It was just that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. good I will convert it as answer for this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have redirected the button click events to `PlaybackRateDownClicked` and `PlaybackRateUpClicked`, so you just need to listen CustomMediaTransportControls 's `PlaybackRate` click event in your main page. For example.

```
var smtc = new  CustomMediaTransportControls(); 
smtc.PlaybackRateDownClicked += Smtc_PlaybackRateDownClicked; 
private void Smtc_PlaybackRateDownClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{   

}
```

For more detail please refer to Handle and [raise events document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event).